# Filtering on full string match but not on substrings

Tags: c#, regex, string, expression

So I've got a long string of numbers and characters and I'd like to filter out a substring. The thing I'm struggling with is that I need a full match on a certain value (starting with S) but this may not be matched in another value.

Input:

```
S10     1+0000000297472+00EURS100    1+0000000297472+00EURS1023P  1+0000000816072+00EUR
```

The input is exactly like this.

Breakdown of input:

```
S10     1+0000000297472+00EUR
```

- Every part starts with a tag S and ends with EUR
- There are spaces in between because every part has a fixed length

=>

- index 0 : tag 'S' with length 1
- index 1 : code with length 7
- index 8 : numbertype with length 1
- index 9 : sign with length 1
- index 10 : value with length 13
- index 23 : sign with length 1
- index 24 : exponent with length 2
- index 26 : unit with length 3

**I need to match on for example S10 and I only want this substring till EUR. I don't want it to match on S100 or S1023P or any other combination. Only on exactly S10**

Output:

```
S10     1+0000000297472+00EUR
```

I'm trying to use Regex to find my match on 'S + code'. I'm doing a full match on my search query and then as soon as anything follows I don't want it anymore. But doing it like this also discards the actual match as after the S10 the value will follow which will match with [^\d|^\D])+\w

```
 foreach (var field in fieldList)
 {
     var query = "S" + field.BallanceCode;                                
     var index = Regex.Match(values, Regex.Escape(query) + @"([^\d|^\D])+\w").Index;
 }
```

For example when looking for S10

needs to match:

`S10     1+0000000297472+00EUR`

may not match:

```
S10/15  1+0000001748447+00EUR 
S1023P  1+0000000816072+00EUR
S10000001+0000000546546+00EUR
```

Update:

Using this code

```
var index = Regex.Match(values, Regex.Escape(query) + @"\p{Zs}.*?EUR").Index;
```

wil yield S10, S10/15, etc when looked for. However looking for S1000000 in the string doesn't work because there is no whitespace between the code and 1+

**S1000000**1+0000000546546+00EUR

For example when looking for S1000000

needs to match:

`S10000001+0000000297472+00EUR`

may not match:

```
S10     1+0000001748447+00EUR 
S1023P  1+0000000816072+00EUR
S10/15  1+0000000546546+00EUR
```

Comment: Why dont use string.substring, i mean you want to check the s + code you know the length so get the string.substring(startingpoint, length) and check that.

Comment: Try `var index = Regex.Match(values, Regex.Escape(query) + @"(?!\d).*?EUR").Index;`.

Comment: @CKY because I don't know the starting point. The example I posted is just 1 small part of a line out of a 20 000 lines file. I need to process each line and the values like my example reappear in each line. Although there are some differences i.e. not every block (S + code) appears in each line

Comment: @stribizhev this matches with `S10/15  1+0000001748447+00EUR` which it shouldn't

Comment: You did not specify the requirements. If there must be a space, then just use `var index = Regex.Match(values, Regex.Escape(query) + @" .*?EUR").Index;`

Comment: @stribizhev as far as I can see, this is doing what I need so you have my graditude. I've edited my post to clarify

Comment: So, when there are 7 digits in the BallanceCode, we do not care about what comes next, right? Then, you need `var index = Regex.Match(values, Regex.Escape(query) + (field.BallanceCode.Length < 7 ? @"\p{Zs}" : "") + ".*?EUR").Index;`.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes that's absolutely what I wanted. Many thanks, I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex that requires a space (or whitespace) to appear right after the `field.BallanceCode`:

```
var index = Regex.Match(values, Regex.Escape(query) + (field.BallanceCode.Length < 7 ? @"\p{Zs}" : "") + ".*?EUR").Index;
```

The regex will match the `S10`, then any horizontal whitespace (`\p{Zs}`),  then any 0 or more characters other than a newline (as few as possible due to `*?`) up to the first `EUR`.

The `(field.BallanceCode.Length < 7 ? @"\p{Zs}" : "")` check is necessary to support a 7-digit `BallanceCode`. If it contains 7 digits or more, we do not check if there is a whitespace after it. If the length is less than 7, we check for a space.

Comment: Just one last question :) will this work aswell? `S10000001+0000000546546+00EUR`
 since now there is no space between the code part and the 1+

Comment: Have a look at [what is matched and what is not](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eS10%5cp%7bZs%7d.*%3fEUR&i=S10+++++1%2b0000000297472%2b00EUR%0d%0a%0d%0amay+not+match%3a%0d%0aS10%2f15++1%2b0000001748447%2b00EUR+%0d%0aS1023P++1%2b0000000816072%2b00EUR%0d%0aS10000001%2b0000000546546%2b00EUR&o=m). I added a `^` and multiline mode just for a demo. Perhaps, you would also like to anchor the regex at the start of string. As far as I understand, the `S10000001+0000000546546+00EUR` should not match, and it is not.

Comment: Well that's a useful site :D It indeed works as intended, but what if I did want to search after S1000000?

Comment: What is the output you'd like to obtain then?

Comment: I'm just trying to find the index of the substring starting with "S + code".
I'm looping over different codes hence why I need S10 but also need S10/15, S1000000 and so forth.. The code part has a different length as you can see. It could also contain a / or a letter. The code part has a maximum length of 7 however and then another part starts (the 1+)

Comment: Are you asking how to get all matches, not just the first? Like `var indices = Regex.Matches(values, Regex.Escape(query) + @"\p{Zs}.*?EUR").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Index).ToList();`?

Comment: No just the first match. I have this string which contains all these "S + codes + values", what I'm doing is looking for these one at a time. So first I look for S10 and I only need the match with S10. Then I need S10/15 and again only need that match. But I'm always looking in the same string, just for a different code.

Comment: I guess you need to use `regex.Match(string source, int Index)`. Try `var rx = new Regex(Regex.Escape(query) + @"\p{Zs}.*?EUR"); index = rx.Match(values, index + 1); while (index > -1) { index = rx.Match(values, index + 1); }`. And you may also check for success each time you perform the search.

Comment: No i'm using a loop and filling in `var query = "S" + field.BallanceCode;`
So basically the query is S10 the first time and I look for it in the string and get its index.
Then the loop ends and I get another code for which I do the same.

Comment: Do you mean [this situation when `S10 xxx EUR` comes after `S10000+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=S10%5cp%7bZs%7d.*%3fEUR&i=S10000001%2b0000000546546%2b00EUR+S10+++++1%2b0000000297472%2b00EUR&o=m)?

Comment: If i'm looking for S10 then yes this is correct, but I also need the opportunity to look for and find S100000 in another iteration. I will always look in the same string containing both these and many more codes and values. But one iteration i'm looking for S10 and another for S10000

Comment: Please think about what you actually need and already have, update the question with full relevant code, and state what it does and what does not. I have no clue what trouble you have but I suspect it is connected with the logics, not the regex.

Comment: I've updated the original question, I hope it's clear now and that you're still willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

So you just want the start (S...) and end (...EUR) of each line and skip everything in between?

```
^([sS]\d+).*?([\d\+]+EUR)$
```

http://regexr.com/3c1ob

Comment: Seen in the question, its not always S10, if that was the case you didnt have to use regex. It can also be s100 or s1000